# Empty response with Keycloak 3.4.1 on Wildfly 11 + Elytron

Tags: cors, wildfly, keycloak, wildfly-11, elytron

I upgraded my application to Wildfly 11 and Keycloak with the new Elytron adapters, but it stopped working. 
I'm using bearer tokens to authenticate an angular application, I think it's something related to CORS because when I manually remove the "Origin" header, the request works and returns the expected result, otherwise it will return an empty response.

1. **This is the correct response (notice I unchecked the Origin header)**

[image: Request WITHOUT Origin header]

2. **This is the empty result**

[image: Request WITH Origin header]

Comment: I have the same problems to use Keycloak 3.4.3 + Elytron in wildfly 11 with Resteasy.

Simply the http status code returns 200 and the data field returns null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a keycloak bug in version 3.4.3-Final

See: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-6414